# for each loop container nested SSIS

Tags: ssis

Can you create a foreach loop container within a foreach loop container?

As the handling of variables for this situation?

Object type have two variables, which take the value of two fields come from a database and query SQL Server 2012 on an Oracle, to return me two camps. The join is with two fields, so I require two for each loop container or otherwise as would be?

Comment: I believe I understand your first question but the rest of your question doesn't quite make sense to me. Could you click the Edit button an try to explain differently what your problem is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can create a ForEach loop nested within another ForEach loop with both applying separate object variables.  Also, each object variable can be defined by one or multiple parameters (Variable Mappings) originating from field value results of SQL queries.  If I understand correctly, you wish to filter the object of the nested ForEach based on the enumeration of the parent ForEach loop container?  That can be done with SQL or via Expressions.